# Count bounded integers with bound on sum

Tags: combinatorics, integers, upper-lower-bounds

Given two integers $x$ and $y$, each with lower and upper bounds ($x_{lb} \leq x \leq x_{ub}$ and $y_{lb} \leq y \leq y_{ub}$), count how many pairs have sum between $s_{lb}$ and $s_{ub}$.

Of course we can first optimise the bounds on the sum:
$$\max(x_{lb} + y_{lb}, s_{lb}) \leq s \leq \min(x_{ub} + y_{ub}, s_{ub})$$

Let's take a concrete example: $-3 \leq x \leq 35$, $-4 \leq y \leq 42$ and we want $3 \leq x + y \leq 15$. From here, I have tried to isolate $y$: $$3 - x \leq y \leq 15 - x$$

But then follow many individual cases that may or may not apply, depending on the length of the intervals of $x$ and $y$.

I intend to programmatically count the number of solutions, in constant time (of course iterating through all values of $x$ would have been significantly easier).

Answer (score 1):

To make things a bit easier we can assume $x_{lb} = 0$ and $y_{lb} = 0$ by adding constants to $x$ and $y$.   In your example, let $u = x + 3, v = y + 4$.  Then you want to count integer solutions to

$$0 \le u \le 38, 0 \le v \le 42, 3 \le (u - 3) + (v - 4) \le 15$$

or

$$ 0 \le u \le 38, 0 \le v \le 42, 10 \le u + v \le 22 $$

In this case only the lower bounds matter - so how many solutions to $10 \le u + v \le 22$ are there where $u$ and $v$ are non-negative integers?     The easiest way to do this is to notice that there are

- $11$ such sums with $u + v = 10$ - $(u,v) = (10, 0), (9, 1), \ldots, (0, 10)$
- $12$ such sums with $u + v = 11$
- and so on, up to $23$ such sums with $u + v = 22$.

So there are $11 + 12 + \cdots + 23$ solutions.  There is a well-known formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression like this - it's the number of terms, in this case $23 - 11 + 1 = 13$, times the average term, in this case $(11 + 23)/2 = 17$, for $13 \times 17 = 221$.  So by knowing this formula you can do it in constant time.

The different cases depending on the length of the intervals are, I think, unavoidable.